For restassured framework, the Extent Reports are not getting generated under report folder
In Eclipse, Extent reports are not generated under report folder and F5 button also not appeared once after running the testng.xml file and there is no error in console window all tests were successful. I do include the extent reports dependency. How can I resolve the problem?
Extent Report Manager Utility:
package api.utilities;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestListener;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.Status;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentSparkReporter;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.configuration.Theme;

public class ExtentReportManager implements ITestListener

{
   public ExtentSparkReporter sparkReporter;
   public ExtentReports extent;
   public ExtentTest test;
   
   String repName;
   
   
   public void onStart(ITestContext testContext)
   {
       String timeStamp=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new Date()); //time stamp
       repName ="Test-Report-"+timeStamp+".html";
       
       sparkReporter=new ExtentSparkReporter("user.dir"+repName); //specify the location of the report
       
       sparkReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("RestAssuredAtomationProject");//Title of the project
       sparkReporter.config().setReportName("Pet Store Users API"); //name of the report
       sparkReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.DARK);
       
       extent=new ExtentReports();
       extent.attachReporter(sparkReporter);
       extent.setSystemInfo("Application","Pet Store Users API");
       extent.setSystemInfo("Operting System",System.getProperty("os.name"));
       extent.setSystemInfo("User Name",System.getProperty("user.name"));
       extent.setSystemInfo("Environment","QA");
       extent.setSystemInfo("User","Kiran");
     } 
     
   public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result)
   {
       test=extent.createTest(result.getName());
       test.assignCategory(result.getMethod().getGroups());
       test.createNode(result.getName());
       test.log(Status.PASS,"Test Passed");
   }
   public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result)
   {
       test=extent.createTest(result.getName());
       test.assignCategory(result.getMethod().getGroups());
       test.createNode(result.getName());
       test.log(Status.FAIL,"Test Failed");
       test.log(Status.FAIL,result.getThrowable().getMessage());
   }
   
   public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult result)
   {
       test=extent.createTest(result.getName());
       test.assignCategory(result.getMethod().getGroups());
       test.createNode(result.getName());
       test.log(Status.SKIP,"Test Skipped");
       test.log(Status.SKIP,result.getThrowable().getMessage());
   }
   
   
   public void OnFinish(ITestContext testContext)
   {
       extent.flush();
   }
}

<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
<listeners>
    <listener class-name="api.utilities.ExtentReportManager"  />
</listeners>

  <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="api.test.UsersTests"/>
      <!--<class name="api.test.UsersTests2"/>-->
      <!--<class name="api.test.DDTests"/>-->
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->

I have added the listeners into testng file. Console output was generated successfully but the report is not generated under report folder.



@halfer - Extent reports is not owned or maintained by TestNG. That was why I removed the tag. So given the brievity of the question, I felt it was not related to TestNG.

@Kiri msr - Can you please edit your question and add information in terms of how you are wiring in this listener into TestNG? You should be using one of the recommended ways of wiring in listeners as explained in the official documentation https://testng.org/#_testng_listeners

@Krishnan: I can give way on this point, but tags are generally not used to indicate who owns a project. It is more of a statement of the relevant technologies that are being used, and since the testng.xml file was mentioned in the text, it felt relevant. However if you are sure it could not be the cause, or useful to mention, do remove it.

@halfer - Thank you for clarifying the intent and I agree with you. Let me wait for the OP to answer my question on the listener wiring in mechanism. Based on that we can take an action on the tags. I have been pruning the TestNG tags based on the relevance of the question to TestNG ( I am a committer in TestNG and so I use the context of having worked on the codebase to do this). I will keep your point in mind going forward. Thank you for your inputs.

@KrishnanMahadevan: Sure, Thank you. sorry for the delayed response. I am in learning phase few things are not getting. The above same code is working in one of tutorial video.I try to replicate the same but unfortunately it fails for me.

@Kirimsr - Please be informed that for the listener to be executed, you should be right clicking on the suite file and then executing it from within eclipse. If you are going to be running just the java class by right clicking on the class from within eclipse, then the listener wouldnt get executed. Can you please clarify on this part?
